# Adobe Flash Player Settings for Android

Tags: settings, microphone, video-recording, adobe-flash

Android Browsers don't have Mic & Cam Settings , is there a way to solve the problem?

**on Computer:**

[image: on Computer]

**on Android:**
but its just a white screen on Android Browsers such as Chrome, Firefox, ...

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve? Might help if people would know what you want to do exactly :)

Comment: @benjaminS I want Adobe Flash Player Settings on the Browser, for Voice and Video Chat. Www.chatonic.com open it on Android .